# Measurement Formatter: space between value and unit

Tags: swift, string, ios10, measurementformatter

I have a `Measurement` attribute:

```
let measurement = Measurement(value: 10000.0, unit: UnitMass.grams)
```

that I want to print as a string. I use the following `MeasurementFormatter`:

```
let measurementFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
measurementFormatter.unitStyle = .short
measurementFormatter.numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

print(measurementFormatter.string(from: measurement))
```

which prints `10,000g`.

How can I get it to print `10,000 g`, i.e. with a space between the value and the unit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the style `.short`. Just comment out this line and it should display a space between them:

```
let measurement = Measurement(value: 10000, unit: UnitMass.grams)
let measurementFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
// measurementFormatter.unitStyle = .short
measurementFormatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
measurementFormatter.numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
print(measurementFormatter.string(from: measurement))    // "10,000 g\n"
```